# Font-awesome not show ONE icon on ASP.NET MVC5 IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, font-awesome

I'm develloping a website using ASP.NET MVC5.
On my footer section, I have 3 icons from Font-Awesome version 4.5.0 -> one for Facebook, onde for Instagram and another one for email.
What's happening is that the icon for Instagram does not appear! The other two works fine.

I tried other versions of font-awesome, tried using it on bundles and not on bundles, also tried it thrugh CDN and nothing...

BUT, when I just created a HTML file, using font-awesome from CDN, the Instagram icon worked correctly.

PS.: If I use another icon instead of "fa fa-instagram", it shows normally.

Is it some IIS configuration?

PS2.: the answers from others posts did not help me, since they are about font-awesome not displaing any icons.

thanks

Comment: Is [this warning](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#brand) relevent to you?

Comment: That's a weird one for sure. If *any* icons show then everything is good. The issue at that point can only be either you're using some class that doesn't actually match an icon (like misspelling "instagram" or something), or there's some rogue factor involved, like Ad Block Plus, like @Shoe mentioned. However, I would expect it to remove facebook as well in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Shoe!
After seeeing the coments on the font-awesome page, I tested and it was the AdBlock Plus indeed.

Although I don't know why the Facebook icon was working and the Instagram icon doesn't...

I've changed the class name on the font-awesome.css: it was "fa-instagram" and I've changed it to "fa-insta" plus changed the name of a class I had used on an "a" tag with the name "instagram" to "insta" so the name of the social network does not appear on the doccument.

After doing this, the icon of the Instagram appeared normally, even with the AdBlock Plus activated.